# Would Thanos have been able to retrieve the Time Stone if Dr. Strange had given it to Dormammu?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

If Dr. Strange had given the Time Stone to Dormammu before he fought Thanos in *Infinity War*, would Thanos have enough power via the five other Infinity Stones to defeat Dormammu and retrieve the Time Stone?

This of course would depend on whether Thanos would have the ability to travel into the Dark Dimension.

Comment: Was there ever even a plan for Dr. Strange to give the stone to Dormammu?

Comment: Why do Dormammu even want any of the stones for? I don't remember him ever showing intent on acquiring any of the stone.

Comment: @Odin 1806, as far as I know, there is no plan like this. I'm just saying that Dr. Strange has the option of giving the Time Stone to Dormammu as a means of keeping the stone away from Thanos and saving half the lives in the Universe.

Comment: @Bernard the Bear, Dormammu probably wouldn't want the Time Stone although he might want it in order to keep Dr. Strange from using it against him in the future if he were to decide to attack Earth again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that highly depends on where the battle takes place. The Dark Dimension is completely controlled by Dormammu (in fact, it's fairly ambiguous if Dormammu is just another name for the Dark Dimension), meaning that Thanos is fighting against someone who's free to alter the rules of the dimension at will. In effect, Thanos would be playing against a stacked deck. So unless Thanos can find the equivalent of a "brain" or a "heart", like that of Ego, I don't think even he would be able to defeat an entire dimension with only 5 infinity stones. However, if Thanos were to somehow get Dormammu out of the Dark Dimension (which for the same reasons above might not even be possible), I think he would definitely make quick work of Dormammu as it appears that the majority of Dormammu's power comes from the Dark Dimension.

This is all highly theoretical, of course, because we don't know what powers Dormammu would have obtained should Dr. Strange have given him the Time Stone. We don't even know if there would be any reality outside of the Dark Dimension left. Dormammu's goal is to devour every planet, and with every planet he devours, his power would grow stronger (as there would be more of "him" around to fight with). The only way we know for certain that Dormammu can be "beaten" is by essentially boring him so much that he leaves. We don't even know if he *can* die, or be defeated in the traditional ways.

PS: I don't see a reason why Thanos couldn't use the Space Stone to travel to the Dark Dimension if he so desired.

TLDR: Unless Thanos can find a way to defeat an entire dimension (made stronger by an Infinity Stone), I think that it's highly likely that Thanos would probably have opted to try to bargain for the stone, or perhaps just continue his quest of annihilation with the five stone he has. The last thing Thanos would want to do is fight Dormammu on his own turf.